# Getting the innerHTML of $event in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i have a html `<div>` with an action listener :

```
<td><div ng-click="tableClick($event)">{{ x }}</div></td>
```

I would like to pass the value of `x` to the `tableClick()` function.
I tried the following (i would like `foreignID` to take the value of `x`) :

```
$scope.tableClick = function(event) {
    var foreignID = event.innerHTML;
};
```

... but it doesn't seems to work (when i try to display the value of foreignID, i get a "undefined").

How can i do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just pass `x` to your function like this:

```
<td><div ng-click="tableClick(x)">{{ x }}</div></td>

$scope.tableClick = function(myVar) {
    var foreignID = myVar;
};
```

There is no need to get it from the html.

Comment: Thanks, it's much simplier indeed.